# First post review created for a user with 10.5k reputation

Tags: support, reputation, review

S.O. presented my this review for a first-post answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/3891721

but when I open the question

[How to find min value of an n digit number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965244/how-to-find-min-value-of-an-n-digit-number)

I saw that the user has a reputation of 10.5k!

How could be possible? Had I misunderstood first-post review mean?

Comment: Welcome to review audits.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think I hit a bug?

Comment: gasp... I already meet some review test, but I think this is unclear: it appear as a bug, why should I have choosed "no action needed"? If it was a bug, at least I want to submit it somewhere...

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a test case used to audit reviewers and make sure they're paying attention. Thus the "Review audit passed" in the above.